# Division of column elements by the largest

Tags: python, list, division

I would like to select the highest value in column `m1` and divide all rows by it, performing the same process for `m2, m3, m4, m5`.
The same process for `d1`, selecting the largest `d1` and dividing all lines by it, the same for `d2, d3, d4, d5`

***Exemplifying:***

```
      m1   d1    m2   d2   ...
0    [70, 2.2]  [71, 1.4]  ...   
1    [71, 0.0]  [68, 0.0]  ...
```

***Data:***

```
#  m1  d1     m2    d2       m3  d3     m4  d4     m5   d5

[[[70, 2.2], [71, 1.41421], [68, 0.0], [69, 2.0], [69, 2.0000]], 
 [[71, 0.0], [68, 0.00000], [69, 2.0], [69, 2.0], [65, 4.8989]]]
```

***Script:***

```
def conversion(data):

    average = []
    temp = []
    most = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        temp.append(data[i][0][0])
    most.append(max(temp))
    for i in range(len(data)):
        average.append(data[i][0][0] / most[0])

    return average
```

***Result:***

```
[0.9859154929577465, 1.0]
```

***Desired Output:***

```
[[[0.985, 1.000],  [1.000, 1.000], [0.981, 0.000], [1.000, 0.000], [1.000, 0.408]], 
 [[1.000, 0.420],  [0.957, 0.000], [1.000, 1.000], [1.000, 0.000], [0.942, 1.000]]]
```

Comment: Just something I noticed. In your `conversion` function, I noticed that `return` is outside of the function. Is this a copying mistake?

Comment: Yes, copy error, corrected, thanks!

Comment: No problem! I just have a question. You say you want to get the highest value in m1 and then divide it by all rows? What rows are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
a = [[[70, 2.2], [71, 1.41421], [68, 0.0], [69, 2.0], [69, 2.0000]], 
 [[71, 0.0], [68, 0.00000], [69, 2.0], [69, 2.0], [65, 4.8989]]]

def conversion(data):
    max_month = 0
    max_day = 0
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i][j][0] > max_month:
                max_month = data[i][j][0]
            if data[i][j][1] > max_day:
                max_day = data[i][j][1]
        for p in range(len(data)):
            if max_month != 0:
                data[p][j][0] = round(data[p][j][0] / max_month, 3)
            if max_day != 0:
                data[p][j][1]  = round(data[p][j][1] / max_day, 3)
        max_month = 0
        max_day = 0
    return data

data = conversion(a)
```

Output:

```
 [[[0.986, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.986, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.408]], [[1.0, 0.0], [0.958, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.942, 1.0]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed when you're iterating through data, you are only looking at values in the m1 column.  Since `len(data)` is two, you are only referencing the m1 row in your final for loop (i.e. the 70 and 71 values).

If you replace your first two loops with these, you can get the maximum m1 and d1 and then iterate over the rows and columns of your (`data[i][j]`) to divide the values.

```
def conversion(data):

    average = []
    temp = []
    most = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        temp.append(data[i][0])        
    
    most = temp[0]
   
    for i in range(1, len(temp)):
        most = [max(most[0], temp[i][0]), max(most[1], temp[i][1])]
    ...
```